# VBA Excel Email Automation every 30 min

Tags: vba, email, automation, recurring

I want an excel file to save (stamp time) every thirty minutes and email itself to me. I have gotten the file to save and send it to me.  However, when I try to do this continuously for 30 min, I run into issues. below is my code, anyone have any ideas? I tried doing a loop function, so while A1 = 0 it will keep running, but when I click stop button, it will change A1 = 1, and basically stop. I also want to be able to run this program and still be able to use excel  and not be disturbed, any ideas?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Range("A1").Value = 0
Do While Range("A1").Value = 0
Loop

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "VBA Email " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & " " & Format(Time, "h.mm AM/PM") & ".xlsm"
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
.to = "xxxx@gmail.com"
.Subject = "VBA Email"
.Attachments.Add (ActiveWorkbook.FullName)
.Display
Application.SendKeys "%s"
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))


End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Range("A1").Value = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: What issues are you running into?  What is it doing that's not what you're expected it to do?  Edit your question to add the information.

Answer (score 0):

To use the loop, enter your statements between the `Do While` line and the `Loop` line:

```
Do While... 
  ' statements here to be executed while
  ' the loop is running
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the Application.Wait function use Application.OnTime 
e.g.

```
Public Sub EventMacro()    
    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:30:00")
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "EventMacro"
    'Save your file and email it
End Sub
```

Comment: Replace "EventMacro" with "CommandButton1_Click" and add the code at the beginning of your procedure